# Angular Material 2 input error matcher callback called many times

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular2-changedetection

I am surprised at the number of times the error matcher function is called on an Angular Material 2 input. See the console output of this plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Bop4v4MtX2Wj6rVwv04P?p=preview

When the page loads, `myErrorStateMatcher` has been called 13 times before you have even touched the input. Every time you click on the input, the function is called 12 more times, and 6 more times when it looses focus.

This most likely is related to Angular's change detection mechanism, but my knowledge of it is a bit limited.

My question i: is it possible to reduce the number of calls to the matcher function ? If this is due to change detection, how can I reduce the number of detections ?

Comment: is there a question somewhere? Your assumption is correct :)

Comment: Just added it :) Sorry for the lack of clarity :)

Comment: It's just a bit unclear what the purpose of this code is. Something related to forms yes. As it is a bit unclear to me the moment, I cannot suggest more than using `(ngModelChange)` here...

Answer (score 1):

The error matcher must be run every change detection cycle because it can potentially be unrelated to the form control it exists on (parent forms submission, sibling validation status, etc). For that reason, you should try to keep the matcher very simple and lean.

You can change your component to use `changeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` and that will cut down the calls significantly. Even better is [this open PR](https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/5692) that will merge soon and should limit calls to 1 or 2 times per interaction